# remove_action from parent theme using child theme functions.php

Tags: php, functions, themes, actions, child-theme

I am trying to remove an action from the parent theme header but I am still not getting any success, here is the class

```
<?php

class theme_Header_Layout{
    public function __construct() {

        add_action('theme_header_layout_1_branding', array( $this, 'get_site_branding' ), 10 );

        add_action('theme_header_layout_1_navigation', array( $this, 'get_site_navigation' ), 10 );

        add_action('theme_site_header_icon', array( $this, 'get_site_header_icon' ), 10 );

        add_action('theme_site_header', array( $this, 'site_skip_to_content' ), 5 );

         *
         *
         *
        add_action('theme_site_header', array( $this, 'site_hero_sections' ), 9999 );
    }
    *
    *
    *
    public function site_hero_sections(){...}
    function hero_block_heading() {...}
    private function alowed_tags(){...}
}

$theme_header_layout = new theme_Header_Layout();
```

And this is what I have on my theme-child functions.php

```
<?php

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
    function theme_enqueue_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    }

    add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_site_hero_sections');
    function remove_site_hero_sections() {
        global $theme_header_layout;
        remove_action('theme_site_header', array($theme_header_layout, 'site_hero_sections'));
    }
```

I've been trying changing the priority inside add_action or remove_action, I've also tried changing the add_action('wp_head'...) to 'theme_site_header' but I am still getting the site_hero_sections on my child theme, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I've been trying changing the priority inside" - so with the `remove_action()`, did you try with 9999? Because when removing an action, the priority needs to match the one used when adding the action.

Comment: Oh wow that's it I guess I probably missed or added an additional "9" but I just copied and pasted the exact same number and now it is working
lol, sorry for bothering you, it is now working as expected, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, all I needed to fix the issue was to add the exact same priority to the remove_action and it worked pretty well, thanks to Sally CJ answer

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_site_hero_sections');
    function remove_site_hero_sections() {
        global $theme_header_layout;
        remove_action('theme_site_header', array($theme_header_layout, 'site_hero_sections'), 9999);
    }
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help, but that wasn't an answer.. 